# Java - Checking if given Character[] has matching parentheses

Tags: java

```
//Given an array of Character consisting of "{[()]}" 
//return true if all parentheses match like above
//return false if all pairs of parentheses expression is say "([{])}" 

public boolean parenthesesMatch(Character [] input) {
    char c1 = '';
    char c2 = '';
    
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length/2; i ++) {
        c1 = input[i];
        c2 = input[input.length-1-i];
        if(c1 == '(') {
           if(c1 + 1 != c2) {
             return false;
           }
        }
        else {
            if(c1+2 != c2) {
               return false;
            }
        }
    }
 return true;
}
```

I realized Character[] input is not char[] input so using ascii values won't work. Any ideas what would work? Should I be using a stack?

Comment: With auto boxing and unboxing, Java will convert `Character` to `char` and vice versa.

Comment: Use stack and put chars in it while passing over the array and popping the char if the consequent item of the array is its "closing" match. Empty stack by the end of the iteration will indicate all parentheses of the array have their match. Will cover cases like `"[{()()}[(){}]]"`.

Answer (score 0):

Use a stack which is LIFO.

Check if character is opening or closing, if it's opening push it onto the stack, if it's closing pop one from the stack and check if the closing character matches the closing brace for the opening brace you have popped.

In the end the stack should be empty if all chars have a matching closing character.

```
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Stack;

public class Linter {

    public static boolean lint(char[] input){
        Stack<Character> stack = new Stack<>();
        for (char c: input) {
            if (isOpeningBrace(c)) {
                stack.push(c);
            } else if (isClosingBrace(c)){
                Character poppedChar = stack.pop();

                if (poppedChar == null){
                    return false; // stack is empty, no matching closing character
                }

                if (isNotMatching(poppedChar, c)){
                    return false; // the popped brace is not matching the closing char
                }
            }
        }

        return stack.isEmpty();
    }

    private static boolean isNotMatching(char openingBrace, char closingBrace){
        Map<Character, Character> matching = Map.of(
            '(',')','[',']','{','}'
        );
        return closingBrace != matching.get(openingBrace);
    }

    private static boolean isOpeningBrace(char c){
        Map<Character, Boolean> openingBraces = Map.of(
            '(', true, '[', true, '{', true
        );
        return openingBraces.get(c) != null;
    }

    private static boolean isClosingBrace(char c){
        Map<Character, Boolean> closingBraces = Map.of(
            ')', true, ']', true, '}', true
        );
        return closingBraces.get(c) != null;
    }

}
```